# Remove a pattern from a character

Tags: r, regex

I have a character like this: `x = "abc [File: abcbdosln}} \n abc \n"`

And I want to remove `File: abcbdosln}} \n` from `x` so that the result would be `"abc [ abc \n"`.

I tried the `gsub` function but have not yet obtained the correct result.

```
gsub("[File].*[\n]", "", x) # this one would remove all the content of x
gsub("File.*\n", "", x, fixed = TRUE) # this one does not work
```

I am trying to solve this problem in a general sense, that is, how to remove this pattern through regular expression.

Comment: If you're asking why it doesn't work, it's because you have the `fixed = TRUE` flag, meaning it is set to read it as a literal string rather than as a regex.

Comment: Thanks, but even though I remove ```fixed = TRUE```, the code does not work either, as it still removes the second ```\n```.

Comment: Try replacing `*` with `+?` (e.g. `gsub("File.+?\n", "", x)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` with `fixed = TRUE` flag means that you want a literal string evaluation, not a regular expression.

Remove the flag, use [non-greedy match](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy) and it will work.

Input:

```
x <- "abc [File: abcbdosln}} \n abc \n"
gsub("File.+?\\n", "", x)
```

Output:

```
"abc [ abc \n"
```